# Is it always true that $(a\cdot b)^{-1}=a^{-1}\cdot b^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given $(G, \cdot)$ a group and $a,b\in G$ is it always true that $(a\cdot b)^{-1}=a^{-1}\cdot b^{-1}$ or does this just hold for abelian groups?

Comment: This holds for all $a, b$ if and only if the group is abelian.  This holds for a particular pair $a,b$ if and only if $ab=ba$.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184894/group-theory-proving-ab-1-a-1-b-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not always true. What **is** always true is that

$$(a\cdot b)^{-1} = b^{-1}\cdot a^{-1}.$$

You can easily verify this, since

$$(a\cdot b)\cdot (b^{-1}\cdot a^{-1}) = a\cdot (b\cdot b^{-1})\cdot a^{-1} = a\cdot e\cdot a^{-1} = a\cdot a^{-1} = e.$$

Answer (score 1):

When you search for counterexample, using matrices, it's not a bad idea. In fact taking $A, B \in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, \space 
B  = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
We have
$$A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, \space 
B^{-1}  = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1\over2 & -{1\over2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

From here
$$(A\cdot B)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\over2 \\
1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Instead
$$A^{-1} \cdot B^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
- {1\over2} & 3\over2 \\
1\over2 & -{1\over2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$